# Converting Timer[] into list type

Tags: java, swing, timer

I need to convert `Timer` into list type and shuffle the array and it not possible to start the timer.

```
protected void stopTimer() throws IOException{ 
       new java.util.Timer().schedule(

    new java.util.TimerTask() {

     Timer tim[] = new Timer[5];
  // LinkedList list = new LinkedList();`
           private java.util.List<Timer> assetList;

           @Override
           public void run() { 
        tim[0] = new Timer(1500,animate);
        tim[1] = new Timer(1500,animate1);
        tim[2] = new Timer(1500,animate2);
        tim[3] = new Timer(1500,animate3);
        tim[4] = new Timer(1500,animate4);
         assetList = Arrays.asList(tim);       
        Collections.shuffle(assetList); 
        assetList.start();  
       System.out.print("iiiiii   === "+assetList);        
          }
  }, 
    5000 
);
  }
```

Here, `assetList.start();` is not working.

Comment: here assetList.start(); not working

Comment: *"I need to.."* ..ask a question, rather than list the requirements.  What is your *question?*

Comment: @AshikAshok I edited the question with your (quite important) comment.

Answer (score 1):

You do have a list of `Timer`s. However, you are trying to call the method `start()` on this list. `java.util.List` does not have this method.

You need to, in one way or another, pick the `Timer` to start from the list, for example:

```
assetList.get(0).start();
```

The above would start the first timer in the shuffled list.